# $X^4 +1$ Galois Group over $\mathbb{F}_5$

Tags: solution-verification, galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

I had an exam question which was calculate the splitting field of $X^{40}-1$ over $F_5$ and then give its' Galois Group.

Now I simplified the polynomial to products of   polynomials of degree 1 to the power of 5 and times $X^4 + 1$, so it is sufficient to find the splitting field over $X^4 +1 $ right?

So we had a similiar question once and what we did is we took an element $\theta$ which satisfies $\theta^4 = -1$ (I'm not too sure why we can even find something like this) and then looked at $F_5(\theta) = {a+b \theta \; a,b \in F_5} $ (I'd be grateful if someone could also explain why $F_5(\theta)$ looks like this ).

So now we have a finite field with 25 elements so it is isomorphic to $F_{25}$ and its' Galois group should be of order 2 and it is generated by the Frobenius-Automorphism, so it is isomorphic to $C_2$ and maps $\theta$ to $-\theta$.

I'd be thankful if someone could check if what I did is right and answer my questions (why $\theta$ exists and why the extension is equal to $ a +b\theta$.

For the simplification of the polynomial if someone cares:

$ X^{40} -1 \\ =(X^{20} +1) \cdot (X^{20} -1)\\
=(X^4 +1)^5 \cdot (X^4 -1)^5
\\= (X^4 +1)^5 \cdot (X -1)^5 \cdot (X -2)^5 \cdot (X -3)^5 \cdot (X -4)^5$

Comment: $X^{40}-1=(X^8-1)^5$. The order of $5\bmod 8$ is $n=2$, so the splitting field is $\Bbb{F}_{5^n}$ (the least $n$ such that $\Bbb{F}_{5^n}^\times$ contains a $8$th root of unity) , the Galois group is generated by the Frobenius and has order $n=2$.

Comment: how does the order of 5 correspond to the extension?

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial $X^4 + 1\in \mathbb{F}_5[X]$ is not irreducible: $(X^2 + 2)(X^2 + 3) = X^4 + 1\in \mathbb{F}_5[X]$, and both $X^2 + 2$ and $X^2 + 3$ are irreducible by the fact that $2, 3\in \mathbb{F}_5$ are not squares. Thus $K = \mathbb{F}_5[\theta]/(\theta^2 + 2)$ is a field extension of $\mathbb{F}_5$ of degree $\deg (X^2 + 2) = 2$, and $K$ is spanned as an $\mathbb{F}_5$-vector space by $1, \theta$. (For the latter, note that it's clearly spanned by $1, \theta, \theta^2, \dots$, but $\theta^2 = -2$ in $K$.) Furthermore, $\theta^4 = (-2)^2 = -1\in \mathbb{F}_5$. There's only one finite field of degree $q$ for each prime power $q$, so $K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{25}$.

Comment: I see, did you mean $K = \mathbb{F}_5[X]/(X^2 + 2)$ or are they isomorphic (since that's how our professor did it), if they are I don't see why? And can you explain why such a $\theta$ exists? And why did you mention $\theta^4$ is it necessary here? Last question would be it still is isomorphic to $C_2$ right? Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not saying that such a $\theta$ exists a priori in $\mathbb{F}_{25}$. Rather, I'm saying that the irreducibility of $f(X) = X^2 + 2$ implies that $K = \mathbb{F}_5[X]/(f)$ is a field extension of $\mathbb{F}_5$; and the generator $X$ of $\mathbb{F}_5$ clearly has $f(X) = 0$. Take that to be $\theta$. The bit about $\theta^4$ was just in response to part of your question above. If you're mean that $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{F}_5) = C_2$, then sure: $K$ is a splitting field and thus Galois of degree $[K:\mathbb{F}_5] = 2$, and there's only one group of order $2$.

Comment: thank you so much in advance for what you already have answered. I'm still a bit confused about the generator part. Is it a generator of $\mathbb{F}_5$ or of K? And why does it fulfill $f(X) = 0$ and how do we go from $ \mathbb{F}_5[X]/(f)$ to $\mathbb{F}_5[\theta]/(f(\theta)$)

Comment: Let $A$ denote the polynomial ring over $\mathbb{F}_5$. The ring $A/(f)$ is a field by the fact that $f$ is irreducible. The generator of $A$ (or, more formally, its image under the projection $A \to A/(f)$) is an element of $A/(f)$ that clearly also vanishes under the function $f$; call it $\theta$.

Comment: Sorry I feel kinda stupid for asking such trivial questions but what exactly is the generator of $A$?I think I was confusing some things, so I cleared up some questions myself.
You've been a great help so thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what else I can say. $A = \mathbb{F}_5[X]$ is a polynomial ring; it has $X$ as its generator. Make sure you're not confusing the ring $\mathbb{F}_5[\alpha]$ formed by adjoining an element $\alpha$ in some extension $F/\mathbb{F}_5$ with the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_5[X]$ of polynomials $a_0 + a_1 X + \cdots + a_n X^n$ with all $a_i\in \mathbb{F}_5$.

Comment: I'm fine with stopping this discussion if you want by the way since most of my questions were answered. But maybe it's the language barrier since I don't know all mathematical terms in english but I don't think I've heard the term generator in the context of a ring, so I'm not sure exactly what it means. And if X is literally the generator and not a placeholder for something then I would have thought that the image of X would still be X since it is not in the ideal of $x^2 +2$.